# How to make an optional arg case generic type is void for a function in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a simple function that has a generic type as default void and in this case the arg is optional, but if I provide a generic type string for example the arg is mandatory as a string.

Example:

[image]

Code:

```
function DoSomething<T = void>(arg: T extends void ? undefined : T){
    console.log(arg ?? `printing void`);
}

DoSomething(); // the arg is not required

DoSomething<string>('hello there!'); // the arg is required as string
```

Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAETgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAPACqIC8iAbnDACYB8AFAIYBORAXIhdgA8o2MAwDOteg0QB+ROAbZghbNN5kAlAG8AUAEgICMXAA22AHQm4Rdl1lyABgAcOhWMUmMHGgNw6Avjo6qBg4+IQ2vogA9NGI+NiInESIMBJgcFCIHNgAjiAwOQxBIVi4BMQkYlCuxKwA5HjYJlbxTTkAhPVRsW2JyakSOfmFqkkS1bVEQUA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [overloaded function signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). It is designed to address this kind of scenario: where more than one unique sequence of argument types are accepted by the function. The overload signature pattern also provides context-aware IntelliSense suggestions as you type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKAlALkQNzjAEwG4AoUSWBZMAHgBUA+VAQwCcBzbOrXfYs8NHhIU9Jm3YB+LukQBvEokQQEAZzgAbAKYA6DXHYsO6UgF8SZNCcQB6G4gDyAaQujVUVjDDsmAcgAWWhr6vtZ2ji6WqAFBIWH2zoio7p7eiDCq6WDAWqysWgTIrHAAtohQgYgSICVaYFCIAEYAnuWVKiUADjDarOiutGA1jblMAIwADBPxEQM0QyUjrExhAFSIAHLOJAB+e-sH+yQAogAenVrQBYhjVRw1dVCqADRNIA3scA0TOqgATABWAEAFlkqxscwWSz8gWCcFCRFs6y2LiUaPRSkOexIAEF7rV6og4MBys0LohfCkvOxfOlMmAvlVVKoYOwwMxGtpynBEJ02MxalBckSSVAyVoKVDcr5fn8AMzAgFgiEkcJaKAQHRaoA)

```ts
function fn(): void;
function fn<T>(arg: T): void;
function fn<T>(arg?: T) {
  console.log(arg);
}

fn(); // OK

fn<string>('hello'); // OK

fn('hello'); // OK (string is inferred from the argument by the compiler)

fn<number>(100); // OK

fn<number>(); /* NOK
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.(2554) */

fn<number>('hello'); /* NOK
           ~~~~~~~
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.(2345) */

// etc...
```